# Azure Container App :ImagePullBackOff on legion when using Private image from Azure Container Registry

Tags: azure-container-registry, azure-container-apps

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtOzM.png)
Hello! I am new to Azure Container Registries and Azure Container apps.
I am trying to create a container app using a private image in ACR.
My ACR has admin user turned on for a username and password.
I also have a managed identity with the proper permissions like ACRPull.

Inside I have a flask app listening to port 5000

However, I cant seem to get it working.
Thank you for your help.

I tried using the portal and AZ Cli running commands like:

```bash
az containerapp create --name $CONTAINER_APP_NAME --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP --environment $CONTAINER_APP_ENVIRONMENT --image $IMAGE --target-port 5000 --ingress 'external' --registry-server $REGISTRY_SERVER  --registry-username $ACR_USERNAME  --registry-password $ACR_PASSWORD --user-assigned $IDENTITY_ID --query configuration.ingress.fqdn
```

Comment: What is the error showing after command execution. @Ak99mProgrammer

Comment: Hi! The error showing in Azure portal is Failed Running Status and Pending ImagePullBackOff on legion

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using managing identity for authentication purpose,  there is no need of including credentials like ACR username and password in your script again.

`Image` attribute should contain the below format.

`--image $_REGISTRY_NAME.azurecr.io/$IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGETAG`

To create a container app with private container image, following parameters are required along with the `az containerapp create` CLI command.

```bash
az containerapp create --name "newcont" --resource-group "xxx" --environment "MyContainerappEnvironment" --image "nginx" --target-port 5000 --ingress 'external' --user-assigned "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/userj" --query properties.configuration.ingress.fqdn
```

*Creating app environment with CLI command:*

```bash
az containerapp env create -n <Name> -g xxx --location eastus2
```

[image]

[image]

To check the creation status of a container app, use [`az containerapp show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/containerapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-containerapp-show) CLI command.

Comment: Hey! It is still not working properly. I keep getting the error "

Failed
(View details
)
1/1 Pending:ImagePullBackOff on legion" Thank you for your help!